# connecting Ubuntu to windows

Tags: linux, windows

I have installed Internet Information Services on windows and Apache on "Ubuntu" using apt-get command to install . "Ubuntu" is being run in my virtual box. now i want to connect these two computer together for which i opened fire fox on Ubuntu and entered my windows "IP address" in the address bar .windows firewall is off.

i ran # /etc/init.d/apache2 start to start Apache as well

Result:  link of Microsoft.com/web with a huge IIS 8 on the page .what is wrong ?how can i fix this?

Comment: In what way exactly do you want to connect the computers together?

Comment: using apache on my linux and iis on my windows , i want when i enter the ip address of the other computer ,they can find each other.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "find each other".

Comment: lets put it in the other way : how would you do it if you want to show an html file containing "hello!" , when you enter the IP address of another computer in your browser? I know that if you install apache on ubunto and IIS in windows , this is possible .please let me know if this is wrong ?and if so , how i should do this?i do appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what you are trying to do, but when you write the IP of a computer running either IIS or Apache, you should see a home page, probably the default one if you had never change it.
What are looking forward to do exactly?

- In IIS the default html file is located in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html
- In Apache you should find httpd.conf file, it has the route to the default website, which probably is /www/index.html or something like that

Comment: lets put it in the other way : how would you do it if you want to show an html file containing "hello!" , when you enter the IP address of another computer in your browser? I know that if you install apache on ubunto and IIS in windows , this is possible .please let me know if this is wrong ?and if so , how i should do this?i do appreciate any help

Comment: see if the edit works for you

Comment: Thanks mate , i got the rest of it ...